# Auto Generate REST Client from WADL

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-client

Are there any tools to auto generate a Command Line REST Client from WADL, something close to [xmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) which can generate Bean classes from WSDL?

I have tried [cxf-wadl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-wadl2javaMavenplugin) and [wadl2java](https://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html).

**cxf-wadl2java** : This is throwing a lot of errors in the generated code and is actually generating the Producer classes rather than the consumer classes.

**wadl2java** : Even after fixing the repositories, I was unable to make this thing work. Get a lot of errors and no documentation at all except for what ever is on that specific page.